# Uploading a sonar Quality profile (.xml) programmatically and set it as default

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, sonarqube

I am using chef and one of my recipe needs to upload the sonar quality profile automatically and set it as default. Right now, I am doing it using browser automation using selenium but I dont like it and i dont believe that it is the right way to do.  Has anyone done the upload using some API or a script? Any programming language or specific methods is fine although I am using Ruby (chef is a ruby DSL). Any pointers please?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Mine  is completely selenium-webdriver within a ruby block. I dont get any error. It does work. Since its a browser automation kind of thing, I wanted opinion from others as to what they use if they have done something like this. More technically sound way or the chef way of doing it. I am just looking for ideas. If I get some, I would try it and get rid of the selenium webdriver part. I need to check what Mark O'Connor suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarQube supports a [REST API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) that you could invoke using ruby.

There is a documentation option for:

- [Restore a quality profile](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743276#WebService/api/profiles-RestoreaQualityProfileBackup)
- [Setting profile as default](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743276#WebService/api/profiles-SetaQualityProfileasDefault)

I have never tried these, so I think you'll have to take a look at how Sonar performs profile backups. I would suggest considering an approach where the profile is saved in your cookbook as a template (allowing you to sub values in) and submitted to Sonar as a restoration.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried the above things. IT did not work for me. I get "Error 404 NOT_FOUND". I guess the URL localhost:9000/api is not present. Most of the curl and GET functions mentioned in the links point to localhost:9000/api. Do I need to do something to enable the API?